# vba: date function returns "00:00:00"

Tags: excel, vba

My below code returns "00:00:00", if passed value "DateValue" is null

vba:

```
Public Function forDate(ByVal DateValue As String) As Date
Dim DoDate As Date
If Not IsNull(DateValue) And DateValue <> "" Then
DoDate = CDate(FormatDateTime(DateValue, 1, 10))
forDate = DoDate
End If
End Function
```

How to handle when "DateValue" is null???
please suggest an answer.

Comment: As written, your function does not define a return value for the case you want - you need at least an 'else' statement?,,,

Comment: Do you mean when ´DateValue´ **is** ´Null´ or do you mean when the  value of the variable ´DateValue´ is the four leters word "Null" ?

Comment: @CaBieberach:When "DateValue" variable`s value is "Null".

Comment: @user2002774 Why don't you validate the `DateValue` String before calling the function? That means you will call this function within a function. If NULL you will return empty string, else you can return the `date` format..

Comment: Because you dimetioned DateValue as a String (`ByVal DateValue As String`), you can NOT pass Null as argument. If you try to, VBA will raise an error and the function will NOT be evaluaterd.

Comment: Be careful.  If you had an 'On error resume Next´ in your procedure prior to using the function, it will simply skip the function and therefore the variable Date will be unmodified. (Therefore 0 )

Comment: Can you show a piece of code that causes this function to be called with DateValue set to Null? I think you left all of us who tried to suggest solutions puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

setting a `Date` to null is valid (i.e. will run without error) provided you use `vbNull` and not `Null`. Though it will return `#12/31/1899#` and not `null` itself. You can check you date variable against that known null value later as being your pseudo null value.

Or you could set it to the minimum date `DateSerial(100, 1, 1)` which will return `#1/1/100#`

Comment: `vbNull` is not the same as 'Null'.  `vbNull` is a VBA internal constant with the value of 1.

Comment: @CaBieberach you're right! (kind of misleading...) well then the DateSerial option might be best if he insists on returning a `Date`

Answer (score 1):

This will handle null and/or empty strings:

```
Public Function forDate(ByVal DateValue)
If IsDate(DateValue) Then
    forDate = CDate(DateValue)
Else
    forDate = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End If
End Function
```

Notice I have removed the definitions of the variables to allow NULL to be passed correctly. when used as a function in a spreadsheet, the function will return a `#VALUE!` error if a string that cannot be represented as a date is passed

Example results:
[image: exaple]

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution may be to declare the function with a variant parameter|

```
Public Function forDate(DateValue)
```

When VBA converts NULL to String, it is no longer NULL...

Comment: Floris: No I cant do this,it has to be in date format. I have problems wit other formats.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments for solution

```
Public Function forDate(ByVal DateValue As String) As Date ' will only accept string parameter

End Function

' below function is a variant and can accept string , null 
Public Function forDate(DateValue)
    Dim DoDate As Date
    If DateValue & "" <> "" Then 'this will handle null and empty string


        Else
            'will go here when null or empty string
            DateValue = Null
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Make sure your function accepts null and returns null...it would work.

Comment: You cannot use `=` to assign NULL - you have to `Set` it. Not sure you can set date to Null though...

Answer (score 0):

```vba
Function IsNullDate(ByVal d As Date) As Boolean
    If d = CDate("00:00:00") Then
        IsNullDate = True
    Else
        IsNullDate = False
    End If
End Function

Sub CheckDate()
    Dim d1, d2 As Date
    d1 = Date
    d2 = Empty
    MsgBox "d1= " & IsNullDate(d1) & ",  d2=  " & IsNullDate(d2)
End Sub
```

Running `CheckDate()` has the following output:

> d1= False, d2= True